# Assign integer value based on customer email + date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Context:
I have 2 columns of data:
Col 1: date
Col 2: customer email address

The same customer orders multiple times on different days

Problem:
I want to understand how to assign based on date, and customer email address, whether it's their first time, second time etc.

I have not figure it out and looking for some help :)

Thanks a lot!

Example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LE7hO0ot22N1R-i35cDqG8OWDlZg2x1gE_kCHGdyruA/edit#gid=0

Comment: So what is the desired output? What have you tried?

Comment: The  desired output is that each unique email address has  an  integer value of 1, 2,3 which represents the time they have ordered something.  What  I've tried  is =ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(C2:C),SORT(ROW(C2:C),SORT(ROW(G2:G),DATEVALUE(C2:C),1),1)-MATCH(DATEVALUE(C2:C),SORT(DATEVALUE(C2:C)),0)-ROW()+2))
 but it only  factors in  date, not  sure how  to do multiple conditions email + date

Comment: Rather update your spreadsheet with this information.

Comment: Sure JvdV, I updated it as such but still yielding no results. I would be grateful for your expertise.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: So would your expected results come up if you'd use `=COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)` and drag that down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I tried is to make a running count using `COUNTIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="","",COUNTIFS(C2:C,C2:C,B2:B,"<="&B2:B)))
```

Comment: Yes - this makes total sense! Thanks a lot! A lot  more straight forward than I was putting forward